# The point's gap affects the width of columns of highcharts. Bug?

Tags: highcharts

I have set both a column and a line in one chart, such as the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/dodouwang/wtjbgav0/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            turboThreshold: 10000,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        },
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'column',
        data: [[1497484800000,210000],[1497571200000,120000],[1497744000000,190000]]
    },{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'line_wide',
        data: [[1497484800000,210000],[1497571200000,120000]]
    },{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'line_narrow',
        data: [[1497484800000,210000],[1497498000000,120000]],
        visible: false
    }],
});
```

But I found that if the gap between the points of the line is too narrow(less than one day), then the width of the column is automatic set to no wider than the gap. Is it a bug or a feature?

you can visit the link above, the default show is a column with a "wider" line, it seems all right. But if you unselect the "line_wide" and select the "line_narrow", then the bug accurs.

How to fix it?

P.S.: I have another question of this link's column: I have set the xAxis to 'datetime', and the column data is [[1497484800000,210000],[1497571200000,120000],[1497744000000,190000], and set the Gapping to 0 to make the width of the column as wider as possible. But, when there are only column in the chart(the 2 lines are unselected), why the max width of the column is a "day", not an "hour" or a "minute" or other width?

Comment: It is not bug, as the x-axis interval is changed from 1day to 1hour .Width depends on datetime interval

Comment: @Deep 3015 Do you mean that one series'width will be affected  by another series? Does the document describe this rule? And I found that if I change type from 'line' to 'scatter', the width of the column doesn't change.

Comment: as they share same axis, width will be affected by another series.coming to `scatter` and  `line`  they are different chart types ,`scatter` is represented by points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [series.pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.pointRange) option. Width of the column depends on that value and if it is not configured - *the range will be computed as the distance between the two closest data points* (on axis, so each series which have that specific axis will be taken into the account).

If you set pointRange to 1 day, columns widths will span for 1 day:

```
plotOptions: {
 column: {
  turboThreshold: 10000,
  borderWidth: 0,
  pointRange: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  pointPadding: 0,
  groupPadding: 0
 },
},
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/nogfr6js/